# Flutter - Programmatically backing up SharedPreferences + AppDocsDirectory Files to Drive/iCloud

Tags: flutter

Ideally I'm looking for a simple solution.  :)

My app saves images/audio files inside the app docs directory and also makes use of SharedPreferences.  Now, on my android tablet, all I have to do is go to the Google Backup settings and click "Backup Now."  Then, even through reinstalls, the app is exactly how I left it.

This is great, convenient and super simple. I want to extend this to my users, yet I want an easier way than having to direct them to do exactly what I'm going here to backup my data.  Is there an easy cross platform (give them options for iCloud and Google Drive) way to achieve this?  Thanks!!